# Callbacks with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting a compile error with a std::function callback. Here's the class declaration:

```
class Cloud
{
// ...
public:
    Cloud (std::string end_point) : end_point(end_point) {}
    void operator() (std::function<void(rapidjson::Document)> callback);
};
```

I store the callback in a private variable and then in a function of the class I'm trying to invoke the callback like this:

```
rapidjson::Document document;
this->callback(document);
```

This code gives me the error:

```
/Users/petilodie/Projects/TheGame/client/Classes/Cloud.cpp:67:20: Calling a private constructor of class 'rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>'
```

I'm new to C++ and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `rapidjson::Document` isn't copyable. You need to pass it to the callback by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to C++11 the only way to disable a function to the outside world was to mark it `private`. In this case, they've made the copy-constructor for `rapidjson::Document` private as a way of saying "this object is not copyable".

To solve this, your callback should take the Document by reference:

```
void operator() (std::function<void(rapidjson::Document&)> callback);
```

Comment: Thank you! Code compiles successfully after passing the arg by reference but I now got another error. EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Code=EXC_i386_GPFLT. Do you know what this means? (I am asking in the context of my case)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that exact error but it sounds like something had perhaps gone out of scope. You should attach the debugger and isolate where this is happening, it may or may not be related to the callback.